# Support python2 & python3 using multiple Pipfiles

Tags: pipenv

Loving pipenv so far however am wondering about using it to support both python2.7 & python3.7.

I'm writing a python package that I want to distribute via an internal pypi repository, and I'd like to support both python2.7, and python3.7 (so far I've developed against python2.7). Given I have to specify the python version within the Pipfile the logical conclusion I draw is that I need multiple Pipfiles.

I'm thinking I shall structure my project like so:

```
root  
|  
|-python2.7  
|    |-Pipfile  
|-python3.7  
|    |-Pipfile
```

Any thoughts on that so far? Is that what others would do?

Assuming I'm going to do that I'm going to need to specify which Pipfile to use when running tests and building the package. According to https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/advanced/#configuration-with-environment-variables I can use env var PIPENV_PIPFILE to specify the Pipfile location. This is fine, I'm just surprised there is no option to specify the Pipfile location on the command-line (e.g. `pipenv --pipfile-location`). Is it worth my requesting such a feature?

Any and all comment on the above is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm...I had a rethink after reading:

> The inclusion of [requires] python_version = "3.6" specifies that your application requires this version of Python, and will be used automatically when running pipenv install against this Pipfile in the future (e.g. on other machines). If this is not true, feel free to simply remove this section.

*https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/#specifying-versions-of-python*

I now have just one Pipfile. I build my code in docker containers so I choose an image with the correct version of python (https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=tags) as appropriate

Also:

> Do not keep Pipfile.lock in version control if multiple versions of Python are being targeted.

*https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/#general-recommendations-version-control*